# Installation of node-help module fails

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install node-help module but after repeated attempts i keep getting following error. Is the installation of node-help package broken?

> root@SuperMaN:/mnt/c/Users/aryan/Desktop/CODING/HTML_SCRIPTS/Nodejs/node-help#
>   npm install -g node-help ▌
>   ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
>   WARN engine node-help@2.0.8: wanted: {"node":">=8.11.1"} (current:
>   {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"}) /usr/local/bin/node-help ->
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-help/bin/node-help
>
> > node-help@2.0.8 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-help
> >     node-help --update --no-run
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-help/bin/node-help:6 const { homedir
>   } = require('os');
>         ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
>       at startup (node.js:136:18)
>       at node.js:966:3 npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-help" npm
>   ERR! node v4.2.6 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! node-help@2.0.8 postinstall: `node-help --update --no-run`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the node-help@2.0.8
>   postinstall script 'node-help --update --no-run'. npm ERR! 
>   Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. 
>   npm ERR! If  you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-help package, 
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     node-help --update --no-run npm ERR! 
>   You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm
>   ERR!     npm bugs node-help npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you
>   can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-help npm ERR!
>   There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   /mnt/c/Users/aryan/Desktop/CODING/HTML_SCRIPTS/Nodejs/node-help/npm-debug.log
>   root@SuperMaN:/mnt/c/Users/aryan/Desktop/CODING/HTML_SCRIPTS/Nodejs/node-help#
>   npm --version
>   3.5.2 root@SuperMaN:/mnt/c/Users/aryan/Desktop/CODING/HTML_SCRIPTS/Nodejs/node-help#
>   node --version v4.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the module requires at least node version 8.11.1
You currently have node: 4.2.6, npm:3.5.2

Try updating. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks after upgrading my node.js module node-help installation went through fine.